# How to multiply PHP variables in this for loop

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting values from a form and trying to multiply them with values on the left hand side incremented in 5s. I added in a picture of the results too.

Code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $costOne = trim($_GET["c1"]);
    $costTwo = trim($_GET["c2"]);
    $costThree = trim($_GET["c3"]);
    $costFour = trim($_GET["c4"]);
    $costFive = trim($_GET["c5"]);
    $minimum = trim($_GET["min"]);
    $maximum = trim($_GET["max"]);
}

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Cost per person<br>Party size</th>';
echo "<th>$costOne</th>";
echo "<th>$costTwo</th>";
echo "<th>$costThree</th>";
echo "<th>$costFour</th>";
echo "<th>$costFive</th>";
echo '</tr>';


for ($col=$minimum; $col <= $maximum; $col+=5) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$col</td>";
    echo "<td>$col*$costOne</td>";
    echo "<td>$col*$costTwo</td>";
    echo "<td>$col*$costThree</td>";
    echo "<td>$col*$costFour</td>";
    echo "<td>$col*$costFive</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxhhD.png)

Comment: You might want to look at input cleaning and escaping. Add atleast is_numeric().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($col=$minimum; $col <= $maximum; $col+=5) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$col. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$col*$costOne. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$col*$costTwo. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$col*$costThree. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$col*$costFour. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$col*$costFive. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: That worked... thank you so much. What do the periods between the PHP variables do?

Comment: the period symbol is a string concatenator. It helps you to combine strings together into another string.

Comment: You can't perform arithmetic/logical operations inside any string. That's why we need to perform that operation separate of string and then concatenate the resulted value into the HTML to show that in frontend.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I'll remember this for next time. I appreciate that